# Merge Multiple Rankings (different criteria and observations) into one

Tags: ranking

So I have 3 rankings on different sets of companies (different industries) and each of them was elaborated based on the key performance indicators of that particular industry.

I ran a PCA to find the key performance indicators and then a CCA (canonical correlation analysis) to measure the relationship between the input and output indicators.
Then I ran a DEA model based on these input and output indicators.
I repeated the steps above for each set of companies and then got the 3 rankings I mentioned.

Then I merged the 3 sets of data and ran the same steps on it... but the overall ranking I get is not very consistent with the previous ones (ie: I expect that the companies in the 1st 2nd and 3rd position in an industry don't show up in the bottom of the overall ranking).

Anyway... I would like some insights on how to merge these 3 original rankings into a general one more consistent.

Thanks in advance !